# Verificar se uma serie de diretorios de um caminho existe em VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

Sou programador júnior ainda e gostaria de saber se em VB.NET é possível criar uma série de verificações de diretórios para saber se ele existe (não confundir com pega a url direto e verificar); queria mais ou menos assim:

Tenho um caminho `C:\Victor\Programas\Teste`, eu queria que meu programa verificasse se cada diretório desse caminho existe, e se não existir, criar o diretório, para então copiar para dentro deste diretorio o arquivo `junior.txt`.

**Edição**

Realmente eu não sabia que o Create Directory já fazia a parte de criar o diretorio no caso de não exsitir.. Mas tenho uma ultima pergunta se não for encomodar. 
Meu programa tem a função de copiar esse arquivo pra determinado diretorio, dentro do diretorio do programa, como não preciso verificar cada um eu teria que verificar o diretorio pai do arquivo certo? pra usa o metodo do create directory no caso de não existir.. 
  Mas a pergunta é a seguinte como eu vou obter esse ultimo diretorio pai?

Tenho mas ou menos isso:

```
Dim DiretorioOriginal as String = "C:Usures\Victor\Desktop\TesteDiretorios\$Teste\Lu\Ui.txt"
```

O "$" é para min usar o medo split ficando só 
Teste\Lu\Ui.txt << esse diretorio vai ser o mesmo do de dentro do programa

vou copiar esse arquivo para o diretorio do programa:

```
Dim DiretorioProgran as string = application.startup & "\TesteDiretorios\"
```

no caso como vou criar a pasta **teste\lu**

seria mas ou menos assim?

```
Dim r as directoryinfo 
r = new directoryinfo(no caso a string Teste\Lu\Ui.txt)
dim result as string = r 

if system.io.directory.exists("C:Usures\Victor\Desktop\TesteDiretorios\$Teste\Lu\Ui.txt")= true then 


else

system.io.Directory.createdirecory("C:Usures\Victor\Desktop\TesteDiretorios\$Teste\Lu\")

end if
```

Comment: Se você realmente quer saber se existe cada um deles separadamente, divida a string pela barra, e faça um loop que vá testando pedaço por pedaço. C:\, C:\Victor, C:\Victor\Programas etc.

Comment: Brigado por responder, mas tentei fazer o loop e não obteve sucesso, se poder me mostra mas ou menos como posso fazer isso, eu agradeço.

Comment: Editei a minha resposta com informações adicionais que você pediu. Tomei a liberdade de incorporar à sua questão original, o texto postado como resposta (você pode editar suas questões quado quiser incrementá-las).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não é preciso verificar cada subdiretório... o método `Directory.CreateDirectory` vai criar todos os níveis do diretório passado automaticamente para você.

Além disso não há forma segura de verificar com `Directory.Exists` para depois chamar o `Directory.CreateDirectory`. Se uma outra thread ou outro programa criar/deletar o diretório no meio tempo entre a verificação do `Exists` e a criação com `CreateDirectory`, você poderia acabar com uma exceção não tratada.

**A forma mais segura é como se segue:**

- O drive `C:` é a única parte do diretório que existe de fato no exemplo abaixo:

  ```
  Try
      Directory.CreateDirectory("C:\masb\xpto\hifdskgfi\giufdagifgdw")
  Catch
      MessageBox.Show("Não foi possível criar o diretório")
  End Try
  ```

Se entrar no bloco catch, então é porque:

- um arquivo que já existe coincide com o nome de um dos subdiretórios
- o usuário não tem permissão

Para saber qual, será necessário verificar qual é a exceção.

**Edição**

O código copiando o arquivo não deve fazer verificações usando `Exists`. Quase nunca é uma boa ideia usar o método `Exists`. Ficaria assim:

```
Dim DiretorioArquivoOriginal As String = "C:\Users\Victor\Desktop\TesteDiretorios\$Teste\Lu\Ui.txt"
Dim Subdiretorio As String() = DiretorioArquivoOriginal.Split("$".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.None)
If Subdiretorio.Length = 2 Then
    Dim DiretorioArquivoPrograma As String = Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "TesteDiretorios", Subdiretorio(1))
    Dim DiretorioPrograma As String = Path.GetDirectoryName(DiretorioArquivoPrograma)
    Try
        Directory.CreateDirectory(DiretorioPrograma)
        File.Copy(DiretorioArquivoOriginal, DiretorioArquivoPrograma)
    Catch
        MessageBox.Show("Não foi possível copiar o arquivo.")
    End Try
End If
```

Notas:

- Usei o `Path.Combine` para concatenar nomes de diretórios.
- `Path.GetDirectoryName` é usado para pegar o nome do diretório pai do arquivo.

Comment: Obrigador por me responder se poder me ajuda nessa pergunta final eu agradeço.

Comment: Ao que se refere? A parte de mover o arquivo? Ou a de verificar qual exceção ocorreu, quando houver?

Comment: quero só copia o arquvo pra o mesmo diretorio do programa por que la tem uma copia da pasta mas existe uma pasta que n existe ai queria saber como usaria tal metodo antes da copia para criar esse diretorio que n existe.

Comment: Muito Obrigado Miguel, tive muito problema com o directory exist e desse jeito realmente funciona normal. Obrigado denovo.